# Python | find method

Tags: python

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0 , len(string)):
    if ( string[i: ].find(sub_string)) == True:
        count = count +1
    return count


STRING = 'ininini'
SUB_STRING = 'ini'
```

CORRECT OUTPUT : 3

MY OUTPUT : 2

it is not detecting the last substring.

Comment: try `if string[i:].startswith(sub_string):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that

```
string[i:].find(sub_string)
```

returns `-1` if not found or the position if found. You want to test for `0` you're testing for position `1` (aka `True`) (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).

It's not "not detecting the last substring", it's detecting bogus matches.

You could use `startswith` instead:

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
      if string[i:].startswith(sub_string):
        count += 1
    return count
```

Note that using `find` isn't a bad idea at all, since you don't have to slice the string (it's faster), there's a start position parameter which is handy here:

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
      if string.find(sub_string,i) == i:
        count += 1
    return count
```

or in one line:

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
        return sum(1 for i in range(len(string)) if string.find(sub_string,i) == i)
```

note that `string.count(sub_string)` doesn't yield the same result because it doesn't consider overlapping strings, like your solution does.